# How to extract data with field value greater than particular number

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to extract the values/methods which are taking more than particular milliseconds, I am unable to provide correct field separator

```
awk -F'=' '$3>960' file
awk -F'=||' '$3>960' file
```

This is a sample line:

```
logAlias=Overall|logDurationMillis=34|logTimeStart=2019-09-12_05:22:02.602|logTimeStop=2019-09-12_05:22:02.636|logTraceUID=43adbcaf55de|getMethod1=26|getMethod2=0|getMethod3=0|getMethod4=1|getMethod5=8
```

I do not see any result or i see it gives me all the transactions

Comment: Try `awk -F'[=|]' '$4>960' file`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a generic, robust and easily extendible way:

```
awk -F'|' '{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) {
    split($i,kv,"=")
    f[kv[1]]=kv[2]
  }
}
f["logDurationMillis"]>960' file
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use

```
awk -F'[=|]' '$4>960' file
```

Note that `[=|]` is a regex matching either `=` or `|` and the value you want to compare against appears in the fourth field.

See [online demo](https://ideone.com/X2CP4B):

```
s="logAlias=Overall|logDurationMillis=34|logTimeStart=2019-09-12_05:22:02.602|logTimeStop=2019-09-12_05:22:02.636|logTraceUID=43adbcaf55de|getMethod1=26|getMethod2=0|getMethod3=0|getMethod4=1|getMethod5=8
logAlias=Overall|logDurationMillis=980|logTimeStart=2019-09-12_05:22:02.602|logTimeStop=2019-09-12_05:22:02.636|logTraceUID=43adbcaf55de|getMethod1=26|getMethod2=0|getMethod3=0|getMethod4=1|getMethod5=8"
awk -F'[=|]' '$4>960' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
logAlias=Overall|logDurationMillis=980|logTimeStart=2019-09-12_05:22:02.602|logTimeStop=2019-09-12_05:22:02.636|logTraceUID=43adbcaf55de|getMethod1=26|getMethod2=0|getMethod3=0|getMethod4=1|getMethod5=8
```

Comment: Looks good to me, idk why it'd have been downvoted but I upvoted now.

Comment: While this is an excellent solution for the presented case, it is not always true that $4 will represent the requested number. Logfiles that have this format do not always preserve the position. Therefore I would recommend the usage of [Oguz Ismail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57991044/8344060). (To be clear, I did not downvote here)

Comment: Ok, so it may be considered less generic than could be, but I think the soluton is valid since 1) there is no indication in the question that the format is not consistent  and 2) the OP attempt clearly hints that OP is trying to use two chars, `=` and `|`, as field separators.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, this may help you in case your string is not coming in a fixed place.

```
awk '
match($0,/logDurationMillis=[0-9]+/){
  if(substr($0,RSTART+18,RLENGTH-18)+0>960){
    print
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***2nd Solution:***

```
awk '
match($0,/logDurationMillis=[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/.*=/,"",val)
  if(val+0>960){
    print
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I do it:

```
awk -F'logDurationMillis=' '{split($2,a,"[|]")} a[1]>960' file
```

If its log duration `logDurationMillis` you are looking for, I do set it as a line separator.  This way I know for sure the next data is the value to get.  Then split the next data by `|` to get the number in front of it.  Then `a[1]` have your value and you can test it against what you need.  No loop, so should be fast.

Comment: Nitpick: POSIX says a `|` at the beginning of an ERE produces undefined results. You can either escape it or enclose in square brackets to amend

Comment: @oguzismail A small type, `|` is not needed in FS :)